# Satellite Series C75D-B7300

Tags: drivers, 16.04

I recently got this Toshiba C75D-B7300 and I want to mess around with it and I've come across ubuntu which I think is a great OS about getting out of windows 10 (upgraded from windows 8.1).

But before I do anything I just want to ask: if I install Ubuntu, will any of my drivers work or will I have any problems?

Comment: Most probably, you'll be fine. You can run in Live mode (press the *Try Ubuntu* button) on the downloaded ISO (after burning to USB and booting from it) where you can have a look around and test.

Comment: We cannot know about your particular system, so its mostly guesswork for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Android Dev made a great answer, I want to add a few things.

First, I'm going to start out with a bit of a tip. We're here to answer your questions, but we generally don't like having to research your computer to get its specs. People have different variations of the same model, or even custom models, and it can be tricky trying to figure out how to help when there are, say, 5 different possible network cards. With that said, I do appreciate you at least giving the model of the laptop. There are many people who come here to ask who don't give any specifics at all.

Now for an answer.

Even with your model number, I had trouble finding very detailed specs online (even though the PDF I opened from Toshiba said "Detailed Specs"). However, I was able to see that your computer has AMD graphics. With the release of Ubuntu 16.04, AMD cards no longer have proprietary drivers available. The end result of that is usually a huge lack of performance.

If you need to game or watch a lot of videos, I suggest you install Ubuntu 14.04 instead of 16.04. 14.04 still has drivers for AMD cards that will give you good performance. **You cannot install `fglrx` (the AMD proprietary driver) on Ubuntu 16.04. It will break your installation.**

Since I couldn't find any other specs on your model, I have to assume and say everything should work. You should only worry if your Wi-Fi card is a certain Broadcom series or a Realtek. Both have relatively easy fixes, but they are a hassle to set up.

Other than graphics and network, you shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: We both got down voted within 5 seconds. Why?

Comment: I can explain why. The question should be closed as "too broad" and the answers are vere generic too. The only resoanable comment is the one below the question.

Comment: Thank you! Could I get the download link for Ubuntu 14.04! I'm so excited

Comment: @Pilot6 we have questions on "which version of Ubuntu is best for me." IMO, that's more broad than this. We've had plenty of questions saying "will Ubuntu work on X computer." Those aren't really that broad, because they are specific to one computer type. Admittedly, the OP could have actually listed their specs, but I addressed that in my answer. I do not believe that, if you managed to downvote both the answers in 5 seconds, you actually read them. I could be wrong, and I'll gladly apologize for the assumption, but in my mind, my answer is specific. I address OP's graphics issue.....

Comment: .....And I think you are forgetting the attitude of AskUbuntu, which is try to answer questions as best as you can if you think they can be answered. I don't see a reason to mindlessly downvote answers to a question you think is incorrect. You are meant to vote on an answer based on its quality, not on the question's quality.

Comment: @EvanK. Here you are: http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.4-desktop-amd64.iso

Comment: @EvanK. There are simple BitTorrent links here: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads, but the direct downloads for 14.04 have a slightly confusing interface. Tell me if you need them.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Please let's not encourage torrents.

Comment: @AndroidDev Torrents are completely legal and secure. I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Zacharee1 - They'll just create more problems. What's wrong with using normal HTTP downloads?

Comment: @AndroidDev there's nothing wrong. I just couldn't find a page with a simple interface for choosing which arch.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I just gave him the direct link a few comments above.

Comment: @AndroidDev I saw. I just prefer giving people the link to where they can choose what they want (x86 vs x64).

Comment: "which version of Ubuntu is best for me."  are off-topic as well and should be closed.

Comment: @Pilot6 that's not what I've been taught by Meta and other seniors of the site.

Comment: You can ask a question at meta regarding this question ;-)

Comment: @Pilot6 I already asked something similar, and I believe at least the last part of Oli's answer applies: http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15250/question-about-answers

Comment: "_The end result of that is a huge lack of performance._" - not necessarily. I do video editing and watch a lot of videos, as well as sometimes play some games (Minecraft, SuperTuxCart, 0AD), and the performance is great with the open source radeon drivers, for me. @AndroidDev I don't think there's anything wrong with torrents, especially if you / OP already knows how to use them. (Which is quite likely these days..)

Comment: @JonasCz I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu has open-source drivers for almost everything. Everything should work out of the box.

Although, take note that you may have some issues.

It is not too uncommon to have issues with Wi-Fi, and your life is practically over if you have Nvidia Optimus. (The optimus part doesn't apply to you I think, since at least from what I could find you have integrated AMD graphics)

I wasn't able to do any research on the Wi-Fi, since the official "spec sheet" is EXTREMELY vague.

Just burn the 16.04 ISO to a blank DVD, and try it in live mode to check if everything works.

---

I recommend burning to a DVD ^^^ rather than onto a USB drive since for some reason new users always have problems successfully burning a USB stick.

If you don't have a blank DVD, and want to try a USB stick, I recommend this program, because it has the highest success rate: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

Comment: I would recommend using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie) to create a bootable USB drive instead of burning a DVD. Less waste and it's faster ;).

Comment: @Zacharee1 - Well, I'll add something about USB drives, but new users always have problems with USB.

Comment: That's why I suggested Rufus. Super easy.

Comment: This information can be found in http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu?s=1|1.0798